# Solution for redirecting link which is present inside the csv file

Tags: python, csv, webdriver

I want a solution for reading the csv file and redirect the link present inside csv file

- I want solution in any programming language.
- Firstly csv file should be read which consists of links
- Then it should be able to redirect to the links

Comment: You can read the file in python using `open`, and then use the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) built in module to open the link in a new browser tab.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using python, we can use the `pandas` and `urllib` to get your requirement working.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen

df = pd.read_csv("<your_filename>", index_col=None)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    urlopen(row["<column_name_containing_links>"])
```